# Pytorch sending inputs/targets to device

Tags: pytorch, tensor, pycocotools

Currently using the pycocotools 2.0 library.

My train_loader is:

```
train_loader, test_loader = get_train_test_loader('dataset', batch_size=16, num_workers=4)
```

However the training lines of code:

```
        for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
            images, targets = data
            images = images.to(device)
            targets = targets.to(device)
```

Results in error. Variables data, images, and targets are all of class tuple

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 40, in <module>
    images = images.to(device)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to'
```

How can I properly send these to cuda device?'

Edit:

I can send images[0].to(device) no problem. How can I send the rest?

Comment: `.to(...)` is implemented for Tensor and Module. Why are they tuple? What is in these tuples?

Comment: You need to convert them to tensors. `images.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)`

Comment: Attempted above: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: Inside images is: tensor([[[0.4196, 0.4196, 0.4039,  ..., 0.0510, 0.0510, 0.0510],
         ...,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the for loop with as many items as your dataset returns at each iteration.
Here is an example to illustrate my point:

Consider the following dataset:

```
class CustomDataset:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ...
        return a, b, c
```

Notice that it returns 3 items at each iteration.

Now let us make a dataloader out of this:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
train_dataset = CustomDataset()
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)
```

Now when we use `train_loader` we should open the for loop with 3 items:

```
for i, (a_tensor, b_tensor, c_tensor) in enumerate(train_loader):
   ...
```

Inside the for loop's context, `a_tensor`, `b_tensor`, `c_tensor` will be tensors with 1st dimension 50 (`batch_size`).

So, based on the example that you have given, it seems that whatever dataset class your `get_train_test_loader` function is using has some problem. It is always better to seprately instantiate the dataset and then create the dataloader rather than use a blanket function like the one you have.

Comment: If you still cant get it to work update your question with your dataset class